# Selenium Webdriver : I want an alternative and i want to click on the buttons continously

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I want to click on the items, but i want to reduce the number of lines in code. How do i do it. Also i want to run the click operation for 5 times on all the elements below.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='fp-nav']/ul/li[1]/a/span")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='fp-nav']/ul/li[2]/a/span")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='fp-nav']/ul/li[3]/a/span")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='fp-nav']/ul/li[4]/a/span")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='fp-nav']/ul/li[5]/a/span")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='fp-nav']/ul/li[6]/a/span")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='fp-nav']/ul/li[7]/a/span")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='fp-nav']/ul/li[8]/a/span")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='fp-nav']/ul/li[9]/a/span")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='fp-nav']/ul/li[10]/a/span")).click();
```

Comment: Use the findelements, iterate on the loop of found elements and for each of them make 5 clicks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using **JAVA** as the language , please see if the below code helps you out:

```
int i;
try{
    WebElement ele;
    //Iterating through all the 10 elements
    for(i=1;i<=10;i++){
        ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='fp-nav']/ul/li["+i+"]/a/span"));
        //Clicking 5 times on the element
        for(int j=1;j<=5;j++){
                ele.click();
        }
    }
}catch(Throwable e){
    System.out.println("Error came up while clicking the element with xpath: '"+"//*[@id='fp-nav']/ul/li["+i+"]/a/span'"+". "+e.getMessage());
}
```

**NOTE:** It will iterate through all the 10 elements and click on each element 5 times. The only problem that might come up here is, in case the click results in a DOM change then the **StaleElementReferenceException** might come into fray.

Answer (score 0):

I've used array concept in code below. It will click 10 items in each set(5 times).

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
public class clickitems 
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
   String[] element={".//*[@id='fp-nav']/ul/li[1]/a/span", ".//*[@id='fp-nav']/ul/li[2]/a/span",".//*[@id='fp-nav']/ul/li[3]/a/span", ".//*[@id='fp-nav']/ul/li[4]/a/span", ".//*[@id='fp-nav']/ul/li[5]/a/span", ".//*[@id='fp-nav']/ul/li[6]/a/span", ".//*[@id='fp-nav']/ul/li[7]/a/span", ".//*[@id='fp-nav']/ul/li[8]/a/span", ".//*[@id='fp-nav']/ul/li[9]/a/span", ".//*[@id='fp-nav']/ul/li[10]/a/span"};
   WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); // Modify according to your browser
   for(int i = 1; i < 6 ; i++){
       System.out.println("Count : "+ i);
       for(int j = 0; j < element.length ; j++)
        {
         System.out.println(element[j]);
         driver.findElement(By.xpath(element[j])).click();
        }
     }
   }
  }
```